# Add to Array Loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Ruby code is：

```
    a = []
    h = {}
    2.times.each do |i|
      %w(a b c).each do |x|
        h[x] = x + i.to_s
      end
      a << h
    end
```

the result is:

```
a = [{"c"=>"c1", "b"=>"b1", "a"=>"a1"}, {"c"=>"c1", "b"=>"b1", "a"=>"a1"}]
```

but i hope the result is:

```
a = [{"c"=>"c0", "b"=>"b0", "a"=>"a0"}, {"c"=>"c1", "b"=>"b1", "a"=>"a1"}]
```

who can help me.thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `a << h` you have to do `h = {}`. This is because you are assigning a new object to h so that it doesn't override the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

*[Complementary answer]* Are you familiar with the principles of [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)?

```
(0..1).map { |n| Hash[("a".."c").map { |c| [c, "#{c}#{n}"] }] }
#=> {"a"=>"a0", "b"=>"b0", "c"=>"c0"}, {"a"=>"a1", "b"=>"b1", "c"=>"c1"}]
```